# How to generate a random number and assign it to my variable array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, random

I need to create a magic 8 ball web page that generates a random response when a question is typed and they click the button. So far I have the HTML and CSS done:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    var answer;
    var my_num = getRandom(14);
    var responses = Array(15);
    responses[0] = "Ask again later...";
    responses[1] = "Yes";
    responses[2] = "No";
    responses[3] = "It appears to be so";
    responses[4] = "Reply is hazy, please try again";
    responses[5] = "Yes, definitely";
    responses[6] = "What is it you really want to know?";
    responses[7] = "Outlook is good";
    responses[8] = "My sources say no";
    responses[9] = "Signs point to yes";
    responses[10] = "Don't count on it";
    responses[11] = "Cannot predict now";
    responses[12] = "As I see it, yes";
    responses[13] = "Better not tell you now";
    responses[14] = "Concentrate and ask again";

    var RandNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 14);

    var answer = responses[RandNum];

    $("#Response").replaceWith(answer);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Magic 8 Ball</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <header>
      <h1>Magic 8 Ball</h1>
    </header>
    <h3>What would you like to know?</h3>
    <input type="text" name="txtQuestion" id="txtQuestion">
    <br />
    <input type="button" id="btnAsk" value="Ask the 8 Ball">
    <h3>The 8 Ball says:</h3>
    <h3 id="Response">Ask the 8 Ball a question...</h3>
  </div>
  <script src="scripts/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/my_scripts.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I have been working on the JavaScript, but nothing I do seems to generate anything! Here is my code:

I honestly don't know what I am doing wrong. I thought I should create a new array with all the possible responses. Then I generate a random number, and assign that to the array variable to give me a random response. Then I replaced the h3 tag that exists with the response I randomly generated. Sounded good in theory. Yet nothing works when I go to click the button. Even if I manually assign a response, say answer = responses[5], nothing happens. What am I missing here?

Comment: There's no `getRandom()` function.

Comment: Thank you Barmar! You get an upvote for that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few errors in your code. You're targeting `$('button')` when you're using `<input type="button">`.  Updated code below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var responses = [];
  responses[0] = "Ask again later...";
  responses[1] = "Yes";
  responses[2] = "No";
  responses[3] = "It appears to be so";
  responses[4] = "Reply is hazy, please try again";
  responses[5] = "Yes, definitely";
  responses[6] = "What is it you really want to know?";
  responses[7] = "Outlook is good";
  responses[8] = "My sources say no";
  responses[9] = "Signs point to yes";
  responses[10] = "Don't count on it";
  responses[11] = "Cannot predict now";
  responses[12] = "As I see it, yes";
  responses[13] = "Better not tell you now";
  responses[14] = "Concentrate and ask again";
  var answer;

  function getRandom(max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
  }
  $("input[type=button]").click(function() {
    var my_num = getRandom(14);
    var answer = responses[my_num];
    $("#Response").text(answer);
  });
});
```

You don't need to explicitly define the size of an array in Javascript in this case.  In addition, you should use `responses.push` here instead of explicitly setting the items index, but it's not a breaking pattern here.

`getRandom` was not defined, maybe it was elsewhere.  `$.replaceWith` is for replacing elements, not text, so I changed that as well.

Comment: Instead of `responses.push` or assigning to indexes, you should just use an array literal: `responses = [ "blah", "blah", "blah", ...]`

Answer (score 1):

there is no button element in your html, so you must attach event to `"#btnAsk"` also `var my_num = getRandom(14)` will give error since getRandom() has not been defined, and it is not required.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btnAsk").click(function() {
    var answer;

    var responses = Array(15);
    responses[0] = "Ask again later...";
    responses[1] = "Yes";
    responses[2] = "No";
    responses[3] = "It appears to be so";
    responses[4] = "Reply is hazy, please try again";
    responses[5] = "Yes, definitely";
    responses[6] = "What is it you really want to know?";
    responses[7] = "Outlook is good";
    responses[8] = "My sources say no";
    responses[9] = "Signs point to yes";
    responses[10] = "Don't count on it";
    responses[11] = "Cannot predict now";
    responses[12] = "As I see it, yes";
    responses[13] = "Better not tell you now";
    responses[14] = "Concentrate and ask again";

    var RandNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 14);

    var answer = responses[RandNum];

    $("#Response").html(answer);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Magic 8 Ball</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <header>
      <h1>Magic 8 Ball</h1>
    </header>
    <h3>What would you like to know?</h3>
    <input type="text" name="txtQuestion" id="txtQuestion">
    <br />
    <input type="button" id="btnAsk" value="Ask the 8 Ball">
    <h3>The 8 Ball says:</h3>
    <h3 id="Response">Ask the 8 Ball a question...</h3>
  </div>
  <script src="scripts/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/my_scripts.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I didn't see that he had the wrong selector, I couldn't understand why it wasn't reporting an error about the undefined function.

Comment: yeah, i began searching that way too

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript source code should be like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var answer;
    var responses = Array(15);
    responses[0] = "Ask again later...";
    responses[1] = "Yes";
    responses[2] = "No";
    responses[3] = "It appears to be so";
    responses[4] = "Reply is hazy, please try again";
    responses[5] = "Yes, definitely";
    responses[6] = "What is it you really want to know?";
    responses[7] = "Outlook is good";
    responses[8] = "My sources say no";
    responses[9] = "Signs point to yes";
    responses[10] = "Don't count on it";
    responses[11] = "Cannot predict now";
    responses[12] = "As I see it, yes";
    responses[13] = "Better not tell you now";
    responses[14] = "Concentrate and ask again";

    $("input[type=button]").click(function() {
       var RandNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 14);    
       var answer = responses[RandNum];    
       $("#Response").html(answer);
    });
});
```

The `var my_num = getRandom(14);` should be deleted and and you should use `html` insted of `replaceWith` to keep the `#Response` div.